# Estimating occupancy rates from arrival rates

Tags: estimation, stochastic-processes

Let's say the number of hotel rooms in a city is X. We know the arrival rate of visitors every day. We don't know the current occupancy. Is it possible to

1. estimate the occupancy rate over all hotel rooms (assume 1 visitor / room)
2. estimate the distribution of stay duration (assume every visitor stays at least 1 day)

On the flip side, if we knew just the occupancy rate, can we estimate the total number of hotel rooms from the arrival data?

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like a homework question to me. Could you provide some context?

Comment: It isn't a homework question, but the original problem domain isn't hotels -- it is cloud computing. I am merely translating the problem. I am looking for pointers to techniques and approaches that can solve this question. Even -- can it be solved with the given data or is more data required (for example the initial occupancy rate).

Comment: Imagine two jails with the same number of cells and same arrival rate (we can even say it's equal to the departure rate, so occupancy stays constant). One jail has all prisoners stay for a week. Another jail has 90% of the prisoners released same day (zero nights) and 10% stay for 10 weeks. Same arrival rate, same occupancy rate, different distribution of stay duration.

Comment: @jonw Good example.  The difficulty is even more basic than that.  An extreme case is a city with so many hotels that nobody ever has to leave!  This makes it obvious that we need to know the average rate at which people depart hotels, or equivalent information.

Comment: Good points on the distribution. In this case the stay duration is probably a "long tail" distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You need more information. In particular, given the number of rooms and the arrival rate, then the average occupancy rate and the average length of stay are proportional to each other.

Comment: What kind of additional information? If we had the average occupancy rate, could we estimate the average length of stay? Or, if we had the average length of stay, we could estimate the occupancy rate?

Comment: @Chiradeep: With three out of four pieces of information you can estimate  the fourth. Broadly speaking: the product numbers of rooms available times occupancy rate equals the number of rooms occupied each night, which in turn equals the product numbers of arrivals per day times length of stay.